# Broadcast Receiver with inner class not registered

Tags: android, android-intent

I've searched and searched, and tried everything I can think of 5 times. I can not get my broadcast receiver to register.

Currently, in the manifest, in the application element, I have:

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$browserReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mycompany.snapbench.browsertest" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my MainActivity class:

```
public static BrowserReceiver browserReceiver;
```

MainActivity->onCreate:

```
browserReceiver = new BrowserReceiver();
```

And finally, at the end of the MainActivity class:

```
public class BrowserReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Receiver", "I'm pretty sick of this.");
    }
}
```

When I press a button in the app, I run this, as a test:

```
if (isIntentAvailable(this, "com.mycompany.snapbench.browsertest")) {
    Log.e("Intent", "It is there.");
} else {
    Log.e("Intent", "FAIL");
}
```

And, of course, I always get "FAIL" in LogCat. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to make sure you call super.onReceive() first in your BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested two approaches and both worked fine. For both I implemented a a class `SmsReceiver` in an activity called `ContactManager`:

```
public static class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {     
        if (intent != null && SMS_RECEIVED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d("TAG", "SMS received in inner class");
        }
    }
}
```

1. first I registered the receiver in the `onCreate()` method:

   ```
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SmsReceiver.SMS_RECEIVED);
   BroadcastReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
   registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
   ```

   Actually it would be better do register it in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`.
2. secondly I removed my registration code and added the receiver to the manifest:

Both solutions worked pretty well and printed the text *SMS received in inner class*. As far as I see  you didn't declare your inner class `static`. That's might be the error. So simply change it to:

```
public static class BrowserReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: Seems that my problem is in the isIntentAvailable() method. Not sure why it's returning false, but that's another question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

call `registerReceiver` in `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`

```
registerReceiver(browserReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.mycompany.snapbench.browsertest"));
```

remember to `unregisterReceiver(browserReceiver)` in `onDestroy`.